# iOS - Move Apps from Spotlight Search to Home Screen?

Tags: spotlight, ios

I was on iOS 15.0 and following [this guide](https://nerdschalk.com/ios-15-how-to-move-apps-from-spotlight-search-to-home-screen/) to move an app from Spotlight Search to Home Screen, and it didn't work - I dragged the app icon to the right / buttom and held, but the Spotlight screen did NOT disappear, and I couldn't drag it to the home screen.

Is there anything I'm missing in the article?

How do I move an app from Spotlight Search to Home Screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- search for app
- tap and hold icon (so you can move it around)
- tap (with another finger) on „Cancel“ at top right